ORA-01017 invalid username/password 19.9c
I can't connect Oracle 19C with sqlplus / as sysdba
Oracle Linux
[oracle]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jun 5 11:25:22 2024
Version 19.9.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

With SYS (sys/password as sysdba) is OK
[oracle]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jun 5 11:28:24 2024
Version 19.9.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.

sqlnet.ora settings is OK
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

[oracle@]$ groups oracle
oracle : oinstall dba oper backupdba dgdba kmdba racdba

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

suggesting to try sqlplus sys/***password*** as sysdba

I solved it. The solution: SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (BEQ)
